# Not able to see Google Maps APIs Usage Statistics

Tags: google-maps-api-2, usage-statistics, google-console-developer, google-distancematrix-api

API statistics report in Google Console project doesn't show data though we are making hundreds of requests every day. Refer attached screenshot, it always shows blank.
I have billing enabled in project.

[image]

Comment: Which API are you looking at?  Are the requests being made with your key?

Comment: Yes, we are requesting "Google Distance Matrix API" with API key.

Comment: What does the code making the request look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API statistics started showing once I upgraded the plan.

I'm not sure if it's Google's policy to not collect stats for free plan to improve the performance of paid plans.

Comment: SiHa - Thanks, I've enabled billing but still I'm not able to see that dashboard for Distance Matrix API.

Comment: SiHa - please try solution suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549082/google-api-error-over-query-limit-empty-dashboard